# Google maps get list of Point of intrest

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

While requesting to get `point of interests` in google map's API, I am getting only 20 Results from any area or on any Lat, Long.
how can I get all the list of `Point of interests`

[Get Point Of Intrest](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=40.4637,3.7492&types=point_of_interest&radius=50000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the Places API documentation on [accessing additional results](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging), places nearby search or text search returns up to 20 results per query, but each search request can have as many as 60 results divided into 3 pages.

If you have more than 20 results, you will have a `next_page_token` value in the response. Submit a new query passing the `next_page_token` to the `pagetoken` parameter to get the next 20 results.  Like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=[next_page_token from previous query here]&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

With regards to getting more than 60 results

It is stated here on the [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826799#comment14) that it is not feasible due to technical concerns and that would turn the API into a database.